# http post with urdl for passport authentication

Tags: boost, passport.js, boost-asio

I have an express app with passport for authentication.
In my app, I use Urdl [enter link description here](http://think-async.com/Urdl/doc/html/index.html) for HTTP request.

But I would like to pass username and password with Urdl

```
urdl::istream is;
is.set_option(urdl::http::request_method("POST"));
is.set_option(urdl::http::request_content_type("text/plain"));
is.set_option(urdl::http::request_content("username=test&password=test"));
host = urdl::url::from_string(http://some/path, ec);
is.open(host);
```

But it give me a bad request (400)
I try with curl

```
curl -X POST --data "username=test&password=test" http://some/path
```

and it is working, I received the good answer

So I don't really know what is wrong with Urdl

Answer (score 0):

It is not text/plain but application/x-www-form-urlencoded for the content type